# Tooltip not visible in new stack snippet layout due to vertical scrollbar

Tags: bug

The tooltip is partially hidden by an unnecessary (there's a lot of vertical free space on the sidebar) vertical scrollbar:

[image]

I'm using Chrome 51.0 on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr).